# How to represent a many-to-many relationship in a relational database?

Tags: sql, many-to-many, relational-database, one-to-many

I have two tables Country and Region. A Region is a set of one or several Countries. Some Countries are in no Region.

How should I represent this in a relational database? I thought of the two following possibilities:

- Country has a Edition column that includes either null or the Edition that it belongs to. My problem with this: I have been taught nulls are evil in a database.
- Edition has a Countries column that is an array of Country. My problem with this: I have been taught arrays are evil in a database.

What's the best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to create a third table with two columns, one contains CountryID the other RegionID where these are respectively the unique identifiers of Country and Region.

A row in this table means a relationship between a Country and a Region. As you can have more than one row in the table, you can store many-to-many relationships. If there is no relationship ( some countries are in no region ), there is no row in the table.

Here is an example

Table 1 - Country 
ID Name 
1  Spain 
2  France 
3  Germany 
4  Norway 
5  Belguim

Table 2 - Region 
ID Name 
1  Europe 
2  BeneLux 
3  EU Trading Region 
4  ASIA

Table 3 - CountryRegion 
Country Region 
1       1 
2       1 
3       1 
4       1 
5       1 
1       3 
2       3 
3       3 
5       2

Which has expressed the following - 
 
Spain is in Europe  ( Country 1, Region 1 ) 
 
France is in Europe 
Germany is in Europe 
Norway is in Europe 
Belgium is in Europe 
Spain is in EU 
France is in EU 
Germany is in EU 
Belguim is in BeneLux

No countries are in ASIA

Ths may not be geographically complete, or correct but I hope it shows the principle.

Comment: So if I understand well: 1-1 relationship -> use foreign key, all other relationships (many-many, 1-many, 0|1-many, 0|1-1) -> use a third table with foreign keys for both tables?

Comment: Almost correct. For 1..* 0..1 and 1..1 it is usual practice to use just two tables and implement the relationship using foreign keys. However, as you point out, when there is no relationship it can result in a column null - which you may want to avoid. But for *..* it is best to use a third table to implement the relationship.