# Table with arbitrary number of columns for rows

Tags: sql

I want to store the amount of the groceries that I have at home and show me dishes, that I can cook based on that.

I want to be precise as possible, that's why I want to differentiate e.g. between frozen and fresh berries or low fat and normal milk. But I've problems modeling this. I have the following tables:

```
Products          Type             Amounts
id | name         id | name        id | Products.id | Type.id | amount
---|----------    ---|------       ---|-------------|---------|-------
1  | milk         1  | frozen      1  | 1           | 2       | 1l
2  | strawberry   2  | low fat     2  | 1           | 3       | 0.5l
                  3  | organic     3  | 2           | 1       | 500g
                  4  | fresh       4  | 2           | 4       | 250g
```

So far I've no problem, but how would I store a product that has two or more types (e.g. low fat, organic milk)?

Things I could do:

- create `organic milk` and `low fat organic milk` as separate products and drop the `Type` table
- Remove the `Type.id` foreign key and put all types for a product as JSON or as CSV in a new `types` column of `Amounts`
- Limit to `n` types per product and add `n` `Type{1..n}.id` columns to `Amounts` - set a column to NULL if product has less than `n` types

But before I do this, I would love to know if there are better solutions.

Comment: i would also go with below option `create organic milk and low fat organic milk as separate products and drop the Type table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distinguish between a "product", which is generic, and an "item" which is a specific instance of the product in the inventory.

Then "tag" the *items* with properties.  This is essentially an entity-attribute-value relationship.  Rows might be:

```
item    product id          tag
A        1 [milk]           organic
A        1                  low-fat
B        1                  organic
```

The idea is to separate the notion of the "product", which is generic, and "item" which is a specific instance that might have additional tags.

Then an "amounts" table:

```
item     Amount    Unit
A        1         liter
```

The tags could of course be in another table, to ensure consistency within and across products.  For instance, you might ask:  What can I make with the organic items (products) that I have on hand?

Comment: I had the idea using generic products and specific items in my head, but couldn't find a way to bring this together - thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Product <-> Type is a **many to many relationship**. Every product can have many types and there can be many products that are of a certain type. To model this in a relational database, you need a so called **mapping table**. That table would have two columns: `product_id` and `type_id`. Then you insert a row for every relation between a product and a type.

You can find an example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681249/how-to-represent-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-a-relational-database).

Comment: What you are describing is a mapping table. A pivot table is something completely different.